# Laravel 6 - Update function in controller ran but the model is not passed to the controller

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-6

I want to update a record from the `background_check_batches` table. What was done is listing all the records and each has a `status` property (column) that can be changed. Clicking on the `status` value will prompt a popup modal to update the value. Since there are multiple records sharing one model, the form's action is changed using js. The issue here is when submitting the form, requested data is received but the `BackgroundCheckBatch` model id is not. I have previously done this kind of task which is identical but it just doesn't work for some reason. Below are my codes.

> web.php

```
Route::put('/admin/dashboard/background-request/{backgroundrequest}', 'BackgroundCheckBatchController@update')->name('update');
```

> status.blade.php ()

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['BackgroundCheckBatchController@update', -1], 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'adminBackgroundCheckStatusModalForm']) !!}

            @csrf
            @method("PUT")

            <div class="modal__content">
                <select class="table_custom_select" id="Status" name="status">
                        <option class="table_custom_select_pending" value="Pending">Pending</option>
                        <option class="table_custom_select_progress" value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                        <option class="table_custom_select_complete" value="Completed">Completed</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="modal__footer">
                <button type="submit" class="button button_size_m button_theme_primary">Proceed</button>
            </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> BackgroundcheckBatchController

```
public function update(Request $request, BackgroundCheckBatch $backgroundCheckBatch) {
    return $backgroundCheckBatch;
}
```

`return $backgroundCheckBatch;` outputted and empty array, `[]`
I expect it to return the `BackgroundCheckBatch` of the provided id in the URL

If I `return $request;`, it will output like so:

```
{
    _token: "Ax789Dr4VXFVE1vpjtKhEWdBjdCZqARDaNQnk7K8",
    _method: "PUT",
    status: "Completed"
}
```

Do inform me if I'm not providing enough detail

Comment: `'action' => ['BackgroundCheckBatchController@update', -1]` Why are you passing -1 to the controller? That won't find any models.

Comment: from my explanation, the action of the form is changed using js. Since its just one modal for many records. It's a dynamic modal following the bootstrap modal

Comment: in the network tab of inspection look where the request is made. it has to be something like: www.example.com/admin/dashboard/background-request/123

Comment: Try `Log::info(Request::fullUrl());`, then check your log in `storage/logs` to see what the full URL is showing.

Comment: @RamūnasPabrėža I've checked the network tab, the form data is like stated

Comment: You have to check not form data, but your request url

Comment: @aynber I've done what you asked and the log is `[2020-03-10 14:35:55] local.INFO: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/dashboard/background-request/1`. So the URL is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#implicit-binding), but it doesn't work because your route parameter doesn't match argument name of your controller's method,

Change your route's parameter to snake_case of `$backgroundCheckBatch` (type-hinted argument name of controller's method):

```php
Route::put('/admin/dashboard/background-request/{background_check_batch}', 'BackgroundCheckBatchController@update')->name('update');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use route model binding the name of your parameter in the update function should match the route parameter:

```php
public function update(Request $request, BackgroundCheckBatch $backgroundrequest) {
    return $backgroundrequest;
}
```